# Using a foreign key on multiple fields in one table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, foreign-key

Simple question probably.

For two tables. A one to many relation is created from A -> B, TeamID -> Fk_Team, however there are multiple fields that need to reference this one relationship how does that work.

so

```
A                          B
TeamID                     EventID
teamName                   datetime
teamocation                homeTeam
etc                        awayTeam
                           Weather
                           Fk_team
```

So how do I define that homeTeam and awayTeam both utilise the Fk_Team relationship and that the homeTeam & awayTeam entry must exist in the TeamID.teamName field?

Comment: Why are they referencing the TeamName instead of TeamID?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand.  True they are referencing TeamID for the details of the team name.

Comment: Ok so just keep that in mind for the code I posted below;  obviously replace `dbo.A(teamName)` with `dbo.A(TeamID)`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't implement this as a single constraint; you'll need to create two:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.B ADD CONSTRAINT FK_HomeTeam 
  FOREIGN KEY (homeTeam) REFERENCES dbo.A(teamName);

ALTER TABLE dbo.B ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AwayTeam 
  FOREIGN KEY (awayTeam) REFERENCES dbo.A(teamName);
```

As I alluded to in my comment, it would be much more efficient to store `TeamID` in the two columns in `dbo.B` - this way you are repeating two `INT`s in every row, instead of bulky strings like "Billy Bob's Bait and Tackle Mudhens" or "South Cincinnati Rebel Rockers."

It also makes it much easier to change a team's name (unless the point is to record their historical name at the time the game was played, but even then I would store names over time in some kind of history table, not with every game).